# Solve a recurrence relation with only one case specified?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am supposed to find a generating function for the sequence with recurrence relation

$a_0 = a_1 = 1$, 
and for n ≥ 2 $a_n = 3_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2}$

I am unsure how to go about this. Is it supposed to be $a_n = 3a_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2}$ or am I missing something? How would you go about solving this? I have multiple problems where it seems to be an $a$ missing, just like this one.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Given that $3_{n-1}$ doesn't seem to make any sense in context, I suspect that yes, it's meant to be $3a_{n-1}$. You might want to get in touch with whoever wrote the question to let them know there are typos (and if they're appearing in multiple places then they might have been copy-pasted or automatically generated, either of which needs fixing).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought as well, but unfortunately it is 1:20 AM here, no proffessor is going to answer me. Thank you very much for your opinion.

Comment: That's pretty rough. I would suggest (a) solving the problems on the assumption that there's meant to be an $a$ in there, (b) sending an email or other message to the person running the course to tell them their quiz is broken. Hopefully if your answers are wrong, you'll have covered your bases well enough.

Comment: I doubt it, but it could be $a_n=3^{n-1}-2a_{n-2}$, which you can solve.